# How to tweak my DOMParser to parse "media:content" from RSS on Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, domparser

First, I have this DOMParser class;

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class DOMParser {

    private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {
        // _feed.clearList();
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(xml);
            Log.e("THE XML", xml);
            Log.e("THE URL", url.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            Log.e("MALFORMED EXCEPTION", "1");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create required instances
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setValidating(false);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
                @Override
                public InputSource resolveEntity(String arg0, String arg1)
                        throws SAXException, IOException {
                    if (arg0.contains("Hibernate")) {
                        return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
                    } else {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
            // Parse the xml
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();

                // Get the required elements from each Item
                for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {
                    try {
                        Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                        String theString = null;
                        String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();
                        Log.e("NODE NAME", nodeName);
                        theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        //Log.e("THE STRING", theString);
                        if (theString != null) {
                            if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                                // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                                // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                                _item.setTitle(theString);
                            } else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                                _item.setDescription(theString);

                                // Parse the html description to get the image url
                                String html = theString;
                                org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                                        .parse(html);
                                Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                                _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                            } else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                                // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                                // empty string
                                String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                                        "");
                                _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                            } else if ("link".equals(nodeName)) {

                                // Trying to get the URL as a string
                                _item.setURL(theString);
                            }
                        /*else if ("media:content".equals(nodeName)){
                            _item.setImage(theString);
                            Log.e("THE IMAGE LINK", theString);
                        }*/

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // add item to the list
                _feed.addItem(_item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Return the final feed once all the Items are added to the RSSFeed
        // Object(_feed).
        return _feed;
    }

}  
    }
```

I am trying to parse entries that look like this;

```
<item>
  <title><![CDATA[Oceans Full of 'Aliens' Could Be Hidden Beneath Earth's Surface, Expert Says]]></title>
  <description><![CDATA[Do "aliens" exist on Earth? In a way, experts think so, and they believe that these creatures can be found thriving in massive underground oceans hidden hundreds of miles beneath the Earth's surface.]]></description>
  <guid>http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/33160/20161130/oceans-full-aliens-hidden-beneath-earths-surface-expert.htm</guid>
  <link>http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/33160/20161130/oceans-full-aliens-hidden-beneath-earths-surface-expert.htm</link>
  <media:content url="http://images.natureworldnews.com/data/images/full/37450/earth-ocean.jpg" />
  <media:title type="html"><![CDATA[earth ocean]]></media:title>
  <media:text type="html"><![CDATA[Do "aliens" exist on Earth? In a way, experts think so, and they believe that these creatures can be found thriving in massive underground oceans hidden hundreds of miles beneath the Earth's surface.]]></media:text>
  <category>
      <name><![CDATA[News]]></name>
  </category>
    <pubDate>Wed, 30 Nov 2016 11:02:00 EST</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
  <title><![CDATA[Great Barrier Reef Sees Its Worst Damage on Record]]></title>
  <description><![CDATA[The Great Barrier Reef is reportedly experiencing its worst damage via coral bleaching by far in history. The culprit is none other than the significant increase in water temperatures, which is record high as well. More than half of the coral population in the northern section has perished, while the central and southern centers have been reported to be in better health.]]></description>
  <guid>http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/33132/20161130/great-barrier-reef-sees-worst-damage-record.htm</guid>
  <link>http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/33132/20161130/great-barrier-reef-sees-worst-damage-record.htm</link>
  <media:content url="http://images.natureworldnews.com/data/images/full/37433/great-barrier-reef-sees-its-worst-damage-on-record.jpg" />
  <media:title type="html"><![CDATA[Great Barrier Reef Sees Its Worst Damage on Record]]></media:title>
  <media:text type="html"><![CDATA[Corals in the Great Barrier reef are in danger.
]]></media:text>
  <category>
      <name><![CDATA[News]]></name>
  </category>
    <pubDate>Wed, 30 Nov 2016 09:54:00 EST</pubDate>
</item>
```

Please note that `<media:content>` tag - that is where the URL for the images are present.

My code is throwing the following for every single RSS entry! Can someone explain the `#text` value I see below? And can someone help me code how to extract the image URL and place it in the `setImage` method?

```
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 E/NODE NAME: media:content
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeValue()' on a null object reference
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.parser.DOMParser.parseXml(DOMParser.java:74)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.SplashActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:103)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.SplashActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:97)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
12-01 01:58:36.278 27776-27823/com.example01 E/NODE NAME: #text
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeValue()' on a null object reference
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.parser.DOMParser.parseXml(DOMParser.java:74)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.SplashActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:103)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.SplashActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:97)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
12-01 01:58:36.279 27776-27823/com.example01 E/NODE NAME: media:title
```

And because of this I also get the following exception;

```
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 E/Image URL: http:
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host: http:
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl.getChecked(HttpUrl.java:670)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.getHttpUrlChecked(OkHttpClient.java:165)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:331)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:398)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.image.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:74)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.image.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:27)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at com.climatenews07.image.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:148)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-01 01:58:36.500 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
12-01 01:58:36.501 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
12-01 01:58:36.501 27776-27927/com.example01 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can someone help me code how to extract the image URL

To extract the value of the `url` attribute of the `media:content` element:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
…
if ("media:content".equals(nodeName)) {
    Element contentElement = (Element) thisNode;
    if (contentElement.hasAttribute("url")) {
        String u = contentElement.getAttribute("url");
    }
}
```

That snippet casts the [Node](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) `thisNode` to an [Element](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) so that the `getAttribute(…)` method can then be used to get the value of the `url` attribute.

> My code is throwing the following for every single RSS entry!

The code in the question is doing this:

```java
theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

…when `nchild.item(j)` is, for example, this:

```xml
<media:content url="http://images.natureworldnews.com/data/images/full/37450/earth-ocean.jpg" />
```

So in that case the code is calling `.getFirstChild()` on a `media:content` element that has no children, so that returns `null`. And then the code calls `.getNodeValue()` on that, which leads to the `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeValue()' on a null object reference` error.

It seems the intent of the code is to get the value of the `url` attribute. But an attribute isn’t a child, so `.getFirstChild()` won’t get the `url` attribute. `.getAttribute(…)` should be used instead.

> Can someone explain the #text value I see below

Every `item` element contains not only child elements but also text nodes—because of the space between the elements. `.getChildNodes()` returns the text nodes along with the element nodes.

One way to skip the text nodes is, in the code in the `for` loop, add something like this:

```java
if ("#text".equals(nodeName)) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: The `media:content` `/>` self-closing-tag syntax (or [empty-element tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-empty) as the XML spec calls it) is not a problem. To an XML parser, it is exactly the same as if it has an end tag.

Comment: Did you try putting the `if ("media:content".equals(nodeName))` block right after the `Log.e("NODE NAME", nodeName);` line in your code? If you do, that should certainly cause it get evaluated, because the output snippet in the question shows it logging `NODE NAME: media:content`.

Comment: The issue was because I was checking if "theString" was null before filtering for node names. Of course media:content's string was null. I am sorry, now it is working. Thanks.